Issue displaying banner ads with appodeal and swift
I have been trying to follow this documentation in order to implement appodeal ads inside of my iOS app.
https://docs.appodeal.com/ios/get-started
I have everything (That I know of) successfully initialized but when I try to display a test banner ad, I am not seeing anything. Here is the code That I am trying to use to get started.
public struct AppodealConstants {
static let key: String = "myAppKey"
static let adTypes: [AppodealAdType] = [.interstitial, .banner]
static let testMode: Bool = true
}

    private func initializeAppodealSDK() {
    Appodeal.setAutocache(true, types: [.banner, .interstitial])
    Appodeal.setTestingEnabled(AppodealConstants.testMode)
    Appodeal.setInitializationDelegate(self)
    Appodeal.initialize(withApiKey: AppodealConstants.key, types: [.banner, .interstitial])
}

extension AppDelegate: AppodealInitializationDelegate {
func appodealSDKDidInitialize() {
    print("Appodeal has finished initializing.")
    print("Is Appodeal initialized for banner ads? \(Appodeal.isInitialized(for: .banner))")
}
}

Main ViewController to display banner ad

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Appodeal.setBannerDelegate(self)
        requestBannerAd() 
    }


    func requestBannerAd() {
    let placement = "bannerAd"

    if Appodeal.isInitialized(for: .banner) {
        if Appodeal.canShow(.banner, forPlacement: placement) {
            print("Showing banner ad for placement: \(placement)")
            Appodeal.showAd(.bannerBottom, forPlacement: placement, rootViewController: self)
        } else {
            print("Cannot show banner ad for placement: \(placement). Ad might not be available.")
        }
    } else {
        print("Appodeal is not initialized for banner ads.")
    }
}

func appodealBannerDidLoadAd() {
    print("Banner ad loaded successfully")
}

func appodealBannerDidFailToLoadAd() {
    print("Failed to load banner ad")
}

func appodealBannerDidShowAd() {
    print("Banner ad shown")
}

func appodealBannerDidHideAd() {
    print("Banner ad hidden")
}

func appodealBannerDidClick() {
    print("Banner ad clicked")
}

In my logs, I see
Appodeal is not initialized for banner ads.
Appodeal has finished initializing.
Is Appodeal initialized for banner ads? true

Has anyone tried this before?

Do. you see any request being made when you try to load a banner ad (probably a domain that is related to appodeal)?
